# Netty 4.1.x direct memory monitoring

Tags: java, netty

Question is a follow up question regarding this forum exchange:
[Direct buffer allocation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/netty/cDSYCx_FQd4/jzd3qwj0BAAJ).

Problem is that at some point there was a change introduced to how default implementation is allocating buffers in direct memory, which is not using JMX `com.codahale.metrics.jvm.BufferPoolMetricSet` any more.

Is there a way to monitor direct memory usage without setting:

`-Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory=0`

Answer (score 2):

It is exposed via metrics (getters) on the `PooledByteBufAllocator` and `UnpooledByteBufAllocator`.

Comment: So - I'm using `io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocatorMetric.usedDirectMemory` to monitor the direct memory usage. I get some values, but then I see in logs OutOfDirectMemoryError because the limit is exceeded, which is like more than twice the value reported by metric. Method `io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent#incrementMemoryCounter` that is throwing exception is using different counter `io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent#DIRECT_MEMORY_COUNTER` to track usage. Are those suppose to be related, or I'm making wrong assumption.

Comment: What should I monitor to be aware of OODME error coming?

Comment: @alobodzk, have you figured this out at last?